# Python calling .txt file in same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to access the .txt file in my project folder (in the same folder). But I am kept getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\u200e\u2068useragents.txt'` error.

Code is;

```
USER_AGENT_LIST = "‎⁨useragents.txt"
```

Comment: use the full path to the file

Comment: @HugoDelahaye I did, but still the same issue. I don't know why, keep changing the first character of the address to something like this: '\u200e\u2068

Comment: for some reason you have special unicode characters in youfilename. try deleting it and retyping it

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you have a [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) in your file name value. erase and write the file name again. Check if your editor or IDE has the feature to show invisible control characters. you will be able to see it.